# How can I change my array of values if some other value changes in javascript/html?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm trying to make a webpage to calculate cake prices using this example: http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml 
All the code is also available here.

I want to make the filling price more expensive if their cake is bigger, how can I change this?

So if a user selects a bigger cake I want to increase the price of the filling. Not just with a certain % but with a different amount of $ depending on the size and filling, I would prefer to change the "filling_prices" array depending on the size of the cake.

I tried this:

```
if (cake_prices[selectedCake[i].value] == 20){
  var filling_prices= new Array();
  filling_prices["None"]=0;
  filling_prices["Lemon"]=5;
  filling_prices["Custard"]=5;
  filling_prices["Fudge"]=7;
  filling_prices["Mocha"]=8;
  filling_prices["Raspberry"]=10;
  filling_prices["Pineapple"]=5;
  filling_prices["Dobash"]=9;
  filling_prices["Mint"]=5;
  filling_prices["Cherry"]=5;
  filling_prices["Apricot"]=8;
  filling_prices["Buttercream"]=7;
  filling_prices["Chocolate Mousse"]=12;
}
else{
  var filling_prices= new Array();
  filling_prices["None"]=0;
  filling_prices["Lemon"]=10;
  filling_prices["Custard"]=10;
  filling_prices["Fudge"]=14;
  filling_prices["Mocha"]=16;
  filling_prices["Raspberry"]=20;
  filling_prices["Pineapple"]=10;
  filling_prices["Dobash"]=18;
  filling_prices["Mint"]=10;
  filling_prices["Cherry"]=10;
  filling_prices["Apricot"]=16;
  filling_prices["Buttercream"]=14;
  filling_prices["Chocolate Mousse"]=24;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, how could I make this work? I'm sorry if this is kind of a stupid question but I'm just starting out.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>Cake Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formcalculations.js"></script>
    <link href="styles/cakeform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
    <div id="wrap">
        <form action="" id="cakeform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>
                <legend>Make your cake!</legend>
                <label >Size Of the Cake</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcake" value="Round6" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round cake 6" -  serves 8 people ($20)</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcake" value="Round8" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round cake 8" - serves 12 people ($25)</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcake" value="Round10" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round cake 10" - serves 16 people($35)</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcake" value="Round12" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Round cake 12" - serves 30 people($75)</label><br/>
                <br/>
                <label >Filling</label>

                <select id="filling" name='filling' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="None">Select Filling</option>
                <option value="Lemon">Lemon($5)</option>
                <option value="Custard">Custard($5)</option>
                <option value="Fudge">Fudge($7)</option>
                <option value="Mocha">Mocha($8)</option>
                <option value="Raspberry">Raspberry($10)</option>
                <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple($5)</option>
                <option value="Dobash">Dobash($9)</option>
                <option value="Mint">Mint($5)</option>
                <option value="Cherry">Cherry($5)</option>
                <option value="Apricot">Apricot($8)</option>
                <option value="Buttercream">Buttercream($7)</option>
                <option value="Chocolate Mousse">Chocolate Mousse($12)</option>
               </select>
                <br/>
                <p>
                <label for='includecandles' class="inlinelabel">Include Candles($5)</label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="includecandles" name='includecandles' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
               </p>

                <p>
                <label class="inlinelabel" for='includeinscription'>Include Inscription($20)</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="includeinscription" name="includeinscription" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
                <input type="text"  id="theinscription" name="theinscription" value="Enter Inscription"  />
                </p>
                <div id="totalPrice"></div>

                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <div class="cont_details">
                <fieldset>
                <legend>Contact Details</legend>
                <label for='name'>Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name='name' />
                <br/>
                <label for='address'>Address</label>
                <input type="text" id="address" name='address' />
                <br/>
                <label for='phonenumber'>Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text"  id="phonenumber" name='phonenumber'/>
                <br/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
        </div>
       </form>
    </div><!--End of wrap-->

</body>
</html>
```

I changed

```
if (cake_prices[selectedCake[i].value] == 20){
```

to

```
if (getCakeSizePrice() == 20){
```

in the javascript code, but it doesn't seem to work

Javascript code:

```
/*
This source is shared under the terms of LGPL 3
www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html

You are free to use the code in Commercial or non-commercial projects
*/

 //Set up an associative array
 //The keys represent the size of the cake
 //The values represent the cost of the cake i.e A 10" cake cost's $35
 var cake_prices = new Array();
 cake_prices["Round6"]=20;
 cake_prices["Round8"]=25;
 cake_prices["Round10"]=35;
 cake_prices["Round12"]=75;

 //Set up an associative array
 //The keys represent the filling type
 //The value represents the cost of the filling i.e. Lemon filling is $5,Dobash filling is $9
 //We use this this array when the user selects a filling from the form



// getCakeSizePrice() finds the price based on the size of the cake.
// Here, we need to take user's the selection from radio button selection
function getCakeSizePrice()
{
    var cakeSizePrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the cake the user Chooses name=selectedCake":
    var selectedCake = theForm.elements["selectedcake"];
    //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedCake.length = 4
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedCake.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedCake[i].checked)
        {
            //we set cakeSizePrice to the value of the selected radio button
            //i.e. if the user choose the 8" cake we set it to 25
            //by using the cake_prices array
            //We get the selected Items value
            //For example cake_prices["Round8".value]"
            cakeSizePrice = cake_prices[selectedCake[i].value];
            //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
            //No reason to continue if we get a match
            break;
        }
    }
    //We return the cakeSizePrice
    return cakeSizePrice;
}

  // var filling_prices= new Array();
  // filling_prices["None"]=0;
  // filling_prices["Lemon"]=5;
  // filling_prices["Custard"]=5;
  // filling_prices["Fudge"]=7;
  // filling_prices["Mocha"]=8;
  // filling_prices["Raspberry"]=10;
  // filling_prices["Pineapple"]=5;
  // filling_prices["Dobash"]=9;
  // filling_prices["Mint"]=5;
  // filling_prices["Cherry"]=5;
  // filling_prices["Apricot"]=8;
  // filling_prices["Buttercream"]=7;
  // filling_prices["Chocolate Mousse"]=12;

if (getCakeSizePrice() == 20){
  var filling_prices= new Array();
  filling_prices["None"]=0;
  filling_prices["Lemon"]=5;
  filling_prices["Custard"]=5;
  filling_prices["Fudge"]=7;
  filling_prices["Mocha"]=8;
  filling_prices["Raspberry"]=10;
  filling_prices["Pineapple"]=5;
  filling_prices["Dobash"]=9;
  filling_prices["Mint"]=5;
  filling_prices["Cherry"]=5;
  filling_prices["Apricot"]=8;
  filling_prices["Buttercream"]=7;
  filling_prices["Chocolate Mousse"]=12;
}
else{
  var filling_prices= new Array();
  filling_prices["None"]=0;
  filling_prices["Lemon"]=10;
  filling_prices["Custard"]=10;
  filling_prices["Fudge"]=14;
  filling_prices["Mocha"]=16;
  filling_prices["Raspberry"]=20;
  filling_prices["Pineapple"]=10;
  filling_prices["Dobash"]=18;
  filling_prices["Mint"]=10;
  filling_prices["Cherry"]=10;
  filling_prices["Apricot"]=16;
  filling_prices["Buttercream"]=14;
  filling_prices["Chocolate Mousse"]=24;
}
//This function finds the filling price based on the
//drop down selection
function getFillingPrice()
{
    var cakeFillingPrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the select id="filling"
     var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["filling"];

    //set cakeFilling Price equal to value user chose
    //For example filling_prices["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
    cakeFillingPrice = filling_prices[selectedFilling.value];

    //finally we return cakeFillingPrice
    return cakeFillingPrice;
}

//candlesPrice() finds the candles price based on a check box selection
function candlesPrice()
{
    var candlePrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the checkbox id="includecandles"
    var includeCandles = theForm.elements["includecandles"];

    //If they checked the box set candlePrice to 5
    if(includeCandles.checked==true)
    {
        candlePrice=5;
    }
    //finally we return the candlePrice
    return candlePrice;
}

function insciptionPrice()
{
    //This local variable will be used to decide whether or not to charge for the inscription
    //If the user checked the box this value will be 20
    //otherwise it will remain at 0
    var inscriptionPrice=0;
    //Get a refernce to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the checkbox id="includeinscription"
    var includeInscription = theForm.elements["includeinscription"];
    //If they checked the box set inscriptionPrice to 20
    if(includeInscription.checked==true){
        inscriptionPrice=20;
    }
    //finally we return the inscriptionPrice
    return inscriptionPrice;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var cakePrice = getCakeSizePrice() + getFillingPrice() + candlesPrice() + insciptionPrice();

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Cake $"+cakePrice;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: do you want to double all prices? why do you take an array insrtead of an object?

Comment: How many sizes are there? Or is ther e a formula you can apply to each one?

Comment: @charlietfl There are 4 different sizes. There isn't a formula you can apply.

Comment: Could we see the HTML for this as well please because I believe the problem lies either in the HTML or the virtual handshake between HTML and JS

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't necessarily want to double all prices just change them, this was just as an example. I maybe want to make "lemon" 20% more expensive while "raspberry" 50% more expensive. Also this is the way the example did it so I tried to do it in kind of the same way.

Comment: @Keydose added it

Comment: What about the calculateTotal function as well?

Comment: @Keydose added it

Comment: Great more functions haha, we need to see all of those as well to see where along the line it's going wrong, so all of the functions that are used within calculateTotal  - in future include everything that pertains to what you're doing in your question, so all HTML and JS used within a process for example

Comment: @Keydose Haha I'm sorry thought I was making a really basic mistake. I don't think you need the other functions as I haven't changed them, I just copied them from the example code.

Comment: It's the getCakeSizePrice one that I'm most interested in because my guess is that the if statement isn't working because that function etc. doesn't match the HTML or other JS correctly

Comment: Also where do you define cake_prices?

Comment: @Keydose added both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `filling_prices` when you change cake size. What happens now is that `getCakeSizePrice()` returns 0 at the start of your program. So the `filling_prices` will be set to the cheaper prices and will never change.

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/martitv/pen/WYYdNq?editors=0010

Due to how you program is structured, this should be done in `calculateTotal()`

Create a function like this:

```
var filling_prices;
function setFillingPrices(cakeSizePrice) {
  if (cakeSizePrice == 20){
    filling_prices= new Array();
    filling_prices["None"]=0;
    filling_prices["Lemon"]=5;
    filling_prices["Custard"]=5;
    filling_prices["Fudge"]=7;
    filling_prices["Mocha"]=8;
    filling_prices["Raspberry"]=10;
    filling_prices["Pineapple"]=5;
    filling_prices["Dobash"]=9;
    filling_prices["Mint"]=5;
    filling_prices["Cherry"]=5;
    filling_prices["Apricot"]=8;
    filling_prices["Buttercream"]=7;
    filling_prices["Chocolate Mousse"]=12;
  }
  else{
    filling_prices= new Array();
    filling_prices["None"]=0;
    filling_prices["Lemon"]=10;
    filling_prices["Custard"]=10;
    filling_prices["Fudge"]=14;
    filling_prices["Mocha"]=16;
    filling_prices["Raspberry"]=20;
    filling_prices["Pineapple"]=10;
    filling_prices["Dobash"]=18;
    filling_prices["Mint"]=10;
    filling_prices["Cherry"]=10;
    filling_prices["Apricot"]=16;
    filling_prices["Buttercream"]=14;
    filling_prices["Chocolate Mousse"]=24;
  }
  setFillingPriceText();
}
```

then call it in your `calculateTotal()` like this:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var cakeSizePrice = getCakeSizePrice();
    var fillingPrice = getFillingPrice(cakeSizePrice);
    var candlesPrice = getCandlesPrice();
    var insciptionPrice = getInsciptionPrice();
    var cakePrice = cakeSizePrice + fillingPrice + candlesPrice + insciptionPrice;

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Cake $"+cakePrice;

}
```

I also created a function called `setFillingPriceText()` that updates the options labels/text with the new price when selecting a new cakesize.
It looks like this:

```
function setFillingPriceText() {
  var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
  //Get a reference to the select id="filling"
  var fillingElements = theForm.elements["filling"].options;
  var fillings = Object.keys(filling_prices);
  for(var i = 1; i < fillingElements.length; i++){
    fillingElements[i].text = fillings[i] + "(" + filling_prices[fillings[i]] + "$)";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked like a charm. Solved!